# Power Query - Merged Query Returning Incorrect Result

Tags: join, powerquery

I have 2 tables that are merged on multiple fields, when I preview the result, it is correct (Rank = 712) as can be seen from this image:

[image: Preview of Data is correct]

However when I expand the resultant table, an incorrect value (Rank = 1) appears:

[image: Expanded Data is incorrect]

Has anyone ever seen something like this before?

Comment: Can you provide an example where we can reproduce this?

Comment: I could perhaps send you a sample file, would that be ok?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you sorted Ranking table,find step:"Sorted Rows",and add Table.Buffer outside Table.Sort,like `Table.Buffer(Table.Sort())`,then it will be correct.