# Power Query result doesn't match returned data

Tags: sql, powerquery

This is a [cross-pos](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Query-result-doesn-t-match-returned-data/m-p/893313/highlight/true#M428213)t from the PowerBI forum:

I'm new to Power Query (Desktop) having previously only used it within Excel.

I have an SQL query source that returns the following data when viewed in the Power Query Editor:

[image: 2020-01-08 09_52_15-Window.png]

yet in my report I get the following values for the Cabinet_DocID and Editor_ID:

[image: 2020-01-08 09_55_29-Window.png]

I'm at a loss to explain what has happened to the values highlighted in red above. Why are they displaying as either 1 or two?

The only difference I can see in the source data between the columns that are correct/incorrect is that the values which were changed are numbers not text.

I feel like I am missing something stupid, but can't figure out what it is.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Alex.

PS. It seems like [this response to the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50344231/572634) might answer my question but I haven't done anything to either of these columns so I'm confused AF right now.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so it seems the numbers appearing were as a result of the values being numerical.

My initial attempt at changing the format to text lead to frustration because I didn't realise that the report doesn't automatically update the displayed format of any data displayed until you deselect and re-select all the columns.

This seems like a flaw to me, but I guess it's working as designed..?